# Redux returns only initial state

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, reducers

I want to create a login page. When I enter value to textInput(Email or password) on emulator, it returns INITIAL_STATE(empty string) constantly. And render() in Login.js does not re-render when I enter any input. If I change for instance email, EMAIL_CHANGED case in LoginReducer.js activated but cannot change the state. No error on debugger console. How could I solve this problem?

Main.js

```
  render() {
const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
return (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Login />
  </Provider>
);}}
```

Login.js

```
render(){
const {containerStyle, subContainerStyle, inputStyle} = styles;
return(
  <View style={containerStyle}>
    <View style={subContainerStyle}>
    <TextInput
      placeholder="E-mail"
      style={inputStyle}
      value={this.props.email}
      onChangeText={email => this.props.emailChanged(email)}
    />
    </View>

    <View style={subContainerStyle}>
    <TextInput
      secureTextEntry
      placeholder="Password"
      style={inputStyle}
      value={this.props.password}
      onChangeText={password => this.props.passwordChanged(password)}
    />
    </View>

    <View style={subContainerStyle}>
      {this.renderLoginButton()}
    </View>
  </View>
);}}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
 return {
  email: state.auth.email,
  password: state.auth.password,
  loading: state.auth.loading
};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { emailChanged, passwordChanged,loginWithEmail })(Login);
```

LoginReducer.js

```
import { EMAIL_CHANGED, PASSWORD_CHANGED, LOGIN_USER, LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, LOGIN_USER_FAIL } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
  loading: false
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMAIL_CHANGED:
        console.log(state.email);
        return { ...state, email: action.payload };
    case PASSWORD_CHANGED:
      return { ...state, password: action.payload };
    case LOGIN_USER:
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, loading: false };
    case LOGIN_USER_FAIL:
      return { ...state, loading: false };
    default:
      return { ...state };

  }
};
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import LoginReducer from './LoginReducer';

export default combineReducers({
 auth: LoginReducer
});
```

types.js

```
export const EMAIL_CHANGED = 'email_changed';
export const PASSWORD_CHANGED = 'password_changed';

export const LOGIN_USER = 'login_user';
export const LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS = 'login_user_succes';
export const LOGIN_USER_FAIL = 'login_user_fail';
```

loginActions.js

```
import { EMAIL_CHANGED, PASSWORD_CHANGED, LOGIN_USER, LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, LOGIN_USER_FAIL } from './types';

export const emailChanged = (email) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: EMAIL_CHANGED,
      payload: email
    });
  };
};

export const passwordChanged = (password) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: PASSWORD_CHANGED,
      payload: password
    });
  };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is that you are not passing the `email and password` to thunks.

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    emailChanged: (email) => {
      dispatch(emailChanged(email))
    },
    passwordChanged: (password) => {
      dispatch(passwordChanged(password))
    },
    loginWithEmail: () => {
      // TODO: complete this yourself, as you did not provide what it is in your code.
    },

  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Comment: As @Firu said I am dispathcing props in LoginAction.js. I also tried your code but it did not work. Thanks for answer